# How do you compute negative numbers to fractional powers in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to compute negative numbers to fractional power in C#.

This what I tried to compute the power,

```
Math.Pow(-0.5264, 1.11)--> Result NaN
Math.Pow(-0.5264, 2) --> 0.27709696
Math.Pow(0.5264, 1.11) --> Gives me a result.
```

When the base is positive and the power is of fractional i do get a value. But  it is failing to give result when base as negative value?

When I tried to find power of a negative base it is returning a complex number format a+bi in matlab.

I really have no clue how to achieve it in C#.

Could someone help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: What makes you think is should work?  What would you expect for -2 ^ 1.5 ?

Comment: Works as in [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) descriped: _x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity_ returns _NaN_

Comment: @Tigran is 1.11 odd or even?

Comment: @paparazzo: that's the right point.

Comment: @Silva: look into [Math.Pow() is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367448/c-sharp-math-pow-is-broken)

Comment: You haven't said what value you are expecting. Are you expecting the complex value?

Comment: Since 1.5 is a 3/2 that is different.  What would you expect for -2 ^ 1.11 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate such expression using `System.Numerics.Complex.Pow`:

```
Complex.Pow(-0.5264, 1.11); //(-0,461524987676948, -0,166159219770948)
Complex.Pow(-0.5264, 2).Real; // 0.27709696
Complex.Pow(0.5264, 1.11).Real; // 0.49052441383186784
```

Usual `Math.Pow` returns double which is real number not complex.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.Pow` is behaving correctly according to its specification.

If you want the complex value, and you don't have a complex math library, it's easy enough to compute it.

We know Euler's Identity:

e<sup>ix</sup> = cos x + i sin x

and more specifically

e<sup>iπ</sup> = -1

Therefore

0.5264 e<sup>iπ</sup> = -0.5264

Therefore

(0.5264)<sup>1.11</sup> e<sup>1.11 i π</sup> = (-0.5264)<sup>1.11</sup>

Now use Euler's identity again

(0.5264)<sup>1.11</sup> (cos(1.11 π) + i sin(1.11 π)) = (-0.5264)<sup>1.11</sup>

And so the real part of the number that you're looking for is

(0.5264)<sup>1.11</sup> cos(1.11 π)

And the imaginary part is

(0.5264)<sup>1.11</sup> sin(1.11 π)

And now you have reduced the problem to real-valued functions that you can compute with the ordinary math library.

The moral of the story is: **solve your math problems by doing mathematics**.